# Why $O(\sqrt a)$ is one upper bound of the number of distinct $\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ be any positive integer. Why the number of distinct $\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor$ is at most $O(\sqrt{a})$ where $b$ is any positive integer satisfying $1\le b\le a$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First consider those $b$ with $b \leq \sqrt{a}$; clearly they can give rise to no more than $\sqrt{a}$ numbers of the form $\lfloor \tfrac a b \rfloor$. Then consider those $b$ with $b > \sqrt{a}$: any number of the form $\lfloor \tfrac ab \rfloor$ they give rise to can be at most $\sqrt{a}$; in particular, there can be at most $\sqrt{a}$ of them. Overall, there are no more than $2 \sqrt{a}$ numbers of the form $\lfloor \tfrac ab \rfloor$ with $1 \leq b \leq a$.